# 3D plot of a stationary time series process in R

Tags: r

I want to learn how to plot a stationary time series process in R. For a moment, let's suppose, we have a simple AR(1) process: y(t)= a y(t-1) + e(t). Where, a=0.5. At each point in time, we can assume a random distribution of e(t), using function, rnorm(100,0,0.2). From there, we can find y(t), with initial assumption: y(0)=10. But, still confused to draw a similar 3d chart as shown in the attached figure, using package R. Thanks.